# vim fortran indentexpr issue

Tags: vim, filetype, indent

Strange issue here with getting `indentexpr=FortranGetFreeIndent()` to be set correctly.

The first time I open a file (free form, of course), say `new.f90`, `:set` gives

```
:set
--- Options ---
  autoindent          filetype=fortran    incsearch           smartcase
  autowrite           helplang=en         mouse=a             syntax=fortran
  background=dark     hidden              ruler               textwidth=72
  backup              history=500         shiftwidth=3        ttyfast
  comments=:!,:*,:C   hlsearch            showcmd             ttymouse=xterm2
  commentstring=!%s   ignorecase          showmatch
  backspace=indent,eol,start
  fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,default,latin1
  formatoptions=tcql
  include=^\c#\=\s*include\s\+
  indentexpr=FortranGetFixedIndent()
  indentkeys=0{,0},:,0#,!^F,o,O,e,=~end,=~case,=~if,=~else,=~do,=~where,=~elsewh
ere,=~select,=~endif,=~enddo,=~endwhere,=~endselect,=~elseif,=~type,=~interface,
=~forall,=~associate,=~block,=~enum,=~endforall,=~endassociate,=~endblock,=~ende
num
  printoptions=paper:letter
  runtimepath=~/.vim,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/
vim73,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,~/.vim/after
  suffixes=.bak,~,.swp,.o,.info,.aux,.log,.dvi,.bbl,.blg,.brf,.cb,.ind,.idx,.ilg
,.inx,.out,.toc
  suffixesadd=.f95,.f90,.for,.f,.F,.f77,.ftn,.fpp
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Now, if I manually `:set indentexpr=FortranGetFreeIndent()` and then write some code

```
program testfree
   print *,"Test free format"
end program testfree
```

then the next time I open the file, `:set indentexpr` gives `indentexpr=FortranGetFreeIndent`.

So it appears that "signs are detected in the first five columns of the first 25 lines" (comment quoted from 'fortran.vim') but that the file extension isn't being recognized as .f90 implying free form.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: By way of a >bump< --- I'm able to work around this, as described above. But it would be helpful if someone knows what might be going wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this (or that portion of it that you need):

```
cd
mkdir .vim
cd .vim
mkdir ftplugin
cd ftplugin
vi fortran.vim
```

Then, in fortran.vim:

```
let s:extfname = expand("%:e")
if s:extfname ==? "f90"
   let fortran_free_source=1
   unlet! fortran_fixed_source
else
   let fortran_fixed_source=1
   unlet! fortran_free_source
endif
```

Works -- every time.

Comment: It might be necessary to put this in ~/.vim/filetype.vim -- at least that's what I just had to do on Mac OS X.